# How do I make the title page and signed declaration appear in the table of contents

Tags: miktex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/}}

\title{PYTHON RANDOM TESTER (PRAT) MODULE CODE: COM3600}    
\date{27/10/2015}    
\author{Daniel Ayeni}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\maketitle

\newpage

\begin{center}

  \huge{SIGNED DECLARATION}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `\huge` is a switch, the correct syntax is `{\huge SIGNED DECLARATION}`

Comment: Are you sure the `article` is the most appropriate class?

Comment: @Au101 But, here, you don't want that. Just `\huge SIGNED...`. It is important that the scope of the switch includes a paragraph break to ensure that the spacing is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the `\addcontentsline` command that allows you to manually add items to the table of content (but also the list of figures and lists of tables). In your case:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Title page}
```

Which makes your code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/}}

\title{PYTHON RANDOM TESTER (PRAT) MODULE CODE: COM3600}    
\date{27/10/2015}    
\author{Daniel Ayeni}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Title page}
\maketitle

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Signed declaration}
\begin{center}

  \huge SIGNED DECLARATION

\end{center}

\newpage\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: As noted in the comments `\huge` is a switch. `\huge{abc} de` does the same as `\huge abc de`.

Comment: @cfr I forgot to change that too ... now it is correct.